# Managing and reconciling Stripe subscription items

Tags: node.js, reactjs, stripe-payments

**Goal**

Offer a service which is subscription based and has two tiers (Standard and Pro). The thing that users can subscribe to (we'll call them `albums`), they can create multiple of but each one they create requires another subscription.

- Vacation Album, Standard Tier
- Friendsgiving Album, Standard Tier
- Graduation Album, Pro Tier

Would end up with (JSON Structure for ease of representation)

```
{
  "id": "sub_...",
  "items": {
    "data": [
      {
        "price": {
          "id": "price_...",
          "product": "prod_..."
        },
        "quantity": 2
      },
      {
        "price": {
          "id": "price_...",
          "product": "prod_..."
        },
        "quantity": 1
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**Reasoning with this setup**

- One trial per user avoids trial abuse (Use trial, create new Album, transfer content to active trial, cancel expiring album)

  - Similarly, avoid coupon code abuse
- One subscription and invoice for the user, way easier to manage
- Adding subscriptions doesn’t require getting your wallet back out, checkout process is faster as we’re just increasing the quantity of a subscription item

**Question:**
I need to identity the `album` they are subscribing which has a row in the database, an id that like to be able to reference and / or tie to a stripe record.

It seems like what would end up happening is if a user subscribed 3 things to the same tier, they would end up with 1 subscription, with 1 subscription item, quantity 3.

So, if they cancel one.. I would just reduce the quantity of the item that contains the product and price they selected.

Is this done in practice? As I work through the code managing those items is.. tough because there is no id to reconcile, it’s just a `quantity` value it's making me think there is a better way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

> Is this done in practice?

9/10 times, it's done using metadata keys and values.

In your case, it's a bit awkward, because the items are bundled by quantity, so you might have to do something like this:

```
items:[
   {
      'id':{{stripe_subscriptionItem_id}},
      'price':{{stripe_price_id}},
      'quantity':2,
      'metadata':{
         'item_1':{{your_id_1}},
         'item_2':{{your_id_2}}
   }
]
```

Granted, it would be more straightforward to use separate items for this - each with their own metadata - but there are two problems:

- You would need to have different Prices for each metadata value (Stripe allows you to create variable prices, but metadata is not supported for it).
- You might end up having too many items in your Subscription altogether (Stripe has a limit of 20 different items per Subscription).

Looks like your best option might be to have items bundled by tier, in which case you'll have to build a logic to add / remove metadata from those items as you increase / decrease the quantity.

-- EDIT --

I did make something work with variable separate items and metadata - here's how I did it:

```
const subscription = await stripe.subscriptions.create({
    customer:{{customer}},
    items:[
        {price_data:{
            unit_amount:1000,
            currency:'usd',
            recurring:{interval:'month'},
            product:{{product_id}}
        },
        quantity:1
        },
        {price_data:{
            unit_amount:1500,
            currency:'usd',
            recurring:{interval:'month'},
            product:{{product_id}}
        },
        quantity:1
        }
    ]
});

const addMetadata = await stripe.subscriptions.update(
    subscription.id,{
    items:[
    {
        id:subscription.items.data[0].id,
        metadata:{'id':'X'}
    },
    {
        id:subscription.items.data[1].id,
        metadata:{'id':'Y'}
    }
    ]
});
```

It's what I was mentioning earlier - you can create variable items, which would allow you to build custom items for each 'album', however adding metadata would be a separate affair.

Still, might not help if you're planning on having more than 20 items on your Subscription.

Comment: This is where i landed in my head, essentially keeping keys in the metadata of the subscription item. I was/am a bit concerned about being able to query by that metadata but admittedly I don’t have a use case requiring it yet, given that I can query by subscription and just parse it out.

Comment: I just added an edit to my response, you might find it helpful. Ultimately, I don't think having bundled items is an elegant way of handling your case, but you might be forced to do so anyway.

Comment: Also, regarding the impossibility to query by metadata, it's true that you can't do that for SubscriptionItems. You could do that for Subscriptions though : https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/search Worth mentioning, in case setting this metadata at Subscription-level is a viable alternative for you